# Angular Version Update Issue with Old Angular Application

Tags: angular

I have one project with Angular version of 10: `"@angular/common": "~10.1.0",`

I have to format my system and after that I add Angular (NODEJS) latest.

I have created one more project with latest version of Angular and its `"@angular/common": "^14.2.0",`

Now latest project run properly without issue for ng server, but my old project output this error.

[image]

Is this an issue with Angular version every time ?

Comment: Did you go through all the steps in the [update guide](https://update.angular.io/)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade you application directly from angular 10 to angular 14 ?
Because the recommended approach that I usually followed is to upgrade the application step by step for example in your case I think you should upgrade from 10 to 11 first and then move on sequentially to angular 14 by following angular update guidelines.